# Jar file with manifest file stopped working

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

A jar file I had created in the very past (`xl-importer.jar`) stopped loading. The `MANIFEST.MF` file is the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: class/Client
```

Although there is the `Client` class inside folder /class/ inside the .jar file, I always get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: class/Client (wrong name: Client)`

However when I run `java Client` inside the /class/ folder, application runs fine.

Jar was created some years ago with a 32 bit compiler. My customer moved to Windows 2003 Server some time ago. Is that the reason? Jar file was loading before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) it specifies that Main-Class is specified with :

> Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

So it could be that you need to replace the "/" with a "."

If the class is in a directory called "class" they need to be put in the class package. **"class" is a keyword in java so you can't use it for a package name.** If you change the folder name to somehting else, for instance "classes", and add a package statement to your java file, then reference the class using a "." rather than a "/" it should work. It did with mine anyway :) e.g.

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: classes.Client
```

Client.java:

```
package classes;

public class Client{

//do code...

}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Actually, `Client.class` does not belong to any package. It was a very simple application with 3-4 classes. All classes are in the `class` folder. Any ideas?

Comment: @xpanta If the class is in a directory called "class" they need to be put in the class package. "class" is a keyword in java so you cant use it for a package name. If change the folder name to say "classes" and add a package statement to your java file, then reference the class using a "." rather than a "/" it should work. It did with mine anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

this is what a newer Manifest looks like (java 6)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

My guess is that java 5 used a different protocol.

Try changing the main class as shown above.